# copy "all contain of file.txt " and "replace word in other text file with it " in cmd using any script and any utility

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-word, cmd.exe

I have two files:

- file1.txt
- file2.txt

file1.txt

```
wget --ftp-user=ezyro_19988709 --http-password=....... ftp://ftp.com/ADMIN.txt
```

file2.txt

```
password
```

So now I want to put password from file2 to file1 and replace the dotted area. Now after merging two file output should be like this:

```
wget --ftp-user=ezyro_19988709 --http-password=password ftp://ftp.com/ADMIN.txt"
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: PowerShell [`Get-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), [`Out-File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and [`replace`](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give this a shoot:

Just create a file with `.bat` extension, then put the folowing code in the bat file, you need to create your files (file1.txt that contains the command line, and file2.txt that contains the password), put this two files in the same directory as the .bat file.

Then execute the file, that should work, please tell me if there is any errors.

```
set replacestr=""
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (file2.txt) do call :Foo %%a
goto End

:Foo
set replacestr=%1

call :innerloop  
:innerloop 

echo %replacestr%
call :FindReplace "......." %replacestr% file1.txt

exit /b 

:FindReplace <findstr> <replstr> <file>
set tmp="%temp%\tmp.txt"
If not exist %temp%\_.vbs call :MakeReplace
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%3" /s /b /a-d /on') do (
  for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`Findstr /mic:"%~1" "%%a"`) do (
    echo(&Echo Replacing "%~1" with "%~2" in file %%~nxa
    <%%a cscript //nologo %temp%\_.vbs "%~1" "%~2">%tmp%
    if exist %tmp% move /Y %tmp% "%%~dpnxa">nul
  )
)
del %temp%\_.vbs
exit /b

:MakeReplace
>%temp%\_.vbs echo with Wscript
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo set args=.arguments
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo .StdOut.Write _
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo Replace(.StdIn.ReadAll,args(0),args(1),1,-1,1)
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo end with
```

Comment: you are just great bro !!! Thanks a lot. it works!!!

Comment: happy for you ;)

Comment: Hello sir,I got some problem with this code . I put your code in code.bat and then i try to start code.bat using vbs script in %temp% folder:       File start.vbs contain:                                                     
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c code.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false                                                                              It run fine but its not able to replace "......."  in file1.txt.

Comment: I can see a file name  "_.vbs "in %temp% folder contain code  :                                 with Wscript               
set args=.arguments
.StdOut.Write _
Replace(.StdIn.ReadAll,args(0),args(1),1,-1,1)
end with

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Powershell** installed on your Windows you can open it up and launch this command:

```
(Get-Content fullPathToFile2.txt).replace('string', (Get-Content fullPathToFile1.txt) ) | Set-Content fullPathToFile2.txt
```

Example:

```
(Get-Content I:\b.txt).replace('5', (Get-Content I:\a.txt) ) | Set-Content I:\b.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sir, i don't want to use Powershell as i need universal solution for all my friend out there,want to use any vbscript or any char_string replacement utility for command line like fart.exe.but in this case fart.exe couldn't help me.its lacking these kind of operation.

Comment: I read in the title of your post "[...] using any script and any utility" so I thought Powershell wouldn't have been a problem. However I saw you solved your problem anyway